# Кто может объяснить в чем есть ошибка, не компилируется код

Tags: pascal

Дано натуральное n > 0. Найти произведение первых n простых чисел.
Подсказка: используйте булевскую функцию для проверки,
является число простым числом или нет.(Массивы использовать нельзя)ю

````
var 
  pr,  j,n,i: integer;
  b:boolean; 
   begin

     write('Введите натуральное число N= ');
      readln(n);
         for i:=1 to n do
     
      begin
        j:=2;b:=true;
        while(j<i div 2)and(b) do
               begin 
               if i mod j =0 then b:=false;
          inc(j)
        end;
        begin
          if b then pr:=pr*i;
          writeln(pr);
        end.
        ```
````

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 2):

основной алгоритм:

```
произведение = 1
кол-во простых числе = 0
текущее число = 2

выполнять до тех пор, пока кол-во простых чисел не будет равно N
    проверить текущее число на простоту
    если текущее число простое
        увеличить кол-во простых чисел
        увеличить произведение в текущее число раз
    увеличить текущее число на 1
```

тест на простоту:

```
в цикле от 2 до корня из числа
    если число делится на число из цикла без остатка - выйти с провальным результатом
выйти с успешным результатом
```

Comment: Если правильно понял то вводиться любое число , после нужно организовать счетчик который выводит ряд простых чисел до числа n но вот как этот ряд перемножить

Comment: не накапливайте просто, у вас есть результат, равный 1, нашли первое простое число - умножили результат на него и т.д.