# В чем ошибка в функции ? любое целое число считает простым и вместо произведения первых n простых чисел выдает 0

Tags: pascal

```
 function Simple(x: integer): boolean;
    var
      i: integer;
    begin
      for i := 2 to x div 2 do
        if x mod i = 0 then
        begin
          result := false;
          exit
        end;
      result := true;
    end;
     
    var
      
      g: Integer; 
      f: Longint;
      n:integer;
     
    begin
    
      for g := 2 to n do
        if Simple(g) then
          f := f * n;
        writeln(' Введите n: ');
        readln(n);
      write(f);
    end.
```

Comment: "Подсказка: используйте булевскую функцию для проверки" - где "булевская функция"?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: нужно использовать функцию odd?

Comment: Нет. odd - нечетное, простое - prime.

Comment: Дубликат вопроса: [Кто может объяснить в чем есть ошибка, не компилируется код](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1360194/%d0%9a%d1%82%d0%be-%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%8a%d1%8f%d1%81%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b2-%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc-%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%be%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%bf%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%80%d1%83%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b4)

Comment: Я вижу вы поправили код. Теперь его уже не починить. :)

Comment: В том коде тоже выдавался не верный результат

Comment: @СергейЗиновьев, я заметил, вы работаете в графической среде. В ней есть отладчик. Воспользуйтесь им.

Comment: Какое начальное значение у `f`?

Comment: Как случилось что вы выполняете расчёты до получения `n` от пользователя?

Comment: Предыдущия ваш код я поправил, запустил и получил правильные ответы. Мы не движемся к цели.

Comment: у f:=1 начальное значение

Comment: В коде нет этого оператора.

Comment: Спасибо все понял как , все работает:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function Simple(x: integer): boolean;
var
  i: integer;
begin
  for i := 2 to x div 2 do
    if x mod i = 0 then
    begin
      result := false;
      exit
    end;
  result := true;
end;
 
var
  
  g: Integer; 
  f: Longint;
  n:integer;
  begin
     writeln(' Введите n: ');
    readln(n);
 f:=1;
  for g := 2 to n do
    if Simple(g) then
      f := f * g;
  write(f);
end.
```

Answer (score 0):

Ваша функция присваивает значение необъявленной переменной и ничего не возвращает. Наверное вы хотели вернуть значение из функции: это делает через exit([возвращаемое значение])

```
function Simple(x: integer): boolean;
var
  i: integer;
begin
  for i := 2 to x div 2 do
    if x mod i = 0 then
    begin
      exit(false);
    end;
  exit(true);
end;
```

Comment: так выдает ошибку что неверное количество параметров

Comment: У меня всё работало, прикрепи что выдает и какой у тебя код

Comment: ниже прикрепил.

Comment: `result :=` тоже используется для возврата значений. Есть такая опция `{$modeswitch result+}`. Ошибка не в функции, а в том что её результат не используется. :)

Comment: А как использовать результат?

Comment: Вы и так его в коде в условии используете

Comment: @Letton, уже нет. :) Он пытается влиять на расчёты, но ноль от умножения единицей не станет. А если поправить эту ошибку, то окажется что программа способна выдавать только степени `n`. А если поправить эту ошибку, то окажется что `n` простых чисел не набирается.